# Inno Setup - How to instal many fonts before setup start?

Tags: fonts, inno-setup

I want to install some fonts before setup start, is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. The question is why do you want to do that.

Comment: because i want a different font for my installer appearance/theme. and i'm not sure everyone will see it like i wanted to. so right before the first page shows, the setup quickly install the font. I've use this script | Source: "OZHANDIN.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Oz Handicraft BT"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall | but it only worked after installation. i'm hopping the simplest way. thanks in advance

Comment: Well, now I see the reason but, are you sure you want to install a font to the target system just for the user's impression from your setup ? Personally, I wouldn't like that and I would mark such installer as malware because before saying my "yes" that I want to install your app. you would install a font that I didn't want to my system. Isn't the theme plugin you are using able to load a font directly from file (so you'd just copy it to a temp folder) ? Which theme plugin are you using ?

Comment: thanks for the reply bro. ok then how to extract it to temp folder and apply the font temporarily to my theme? i don't use any plugin, i just edit it on .isl file and change the font name. it works on my pc which already installed the needed font.

Comment: The font from the *.isl file is loaded before any event is fired by the scripting engine, so it's impossible to install font which the installer already attempted to load. I'll be right back with a workaround...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to use external font for the wizard without its installation ?

To register font for a private use to a certain process (in your case the setup), you can use the Windows API function [`AddFontResourceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) called with the [`FR_PRIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#FR_PRIVATE) flag specified in the `fl` parameter. It will allow you to use the font just for your process. In the follwoing example script is shown, how to extract a font to the temporary folder, register it for the private use of the setup process and how to load it to the wizard form controls:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyFont.ttf"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  FR_PRIVATE = $10;
  FR_NOT_ENUM = $20;

function AddFontResourceEx(lpszFilename: string;
  fl: DWORD; pdv: Cardinal): Integer;
  external 'AddFontResourceEx{#AW}@gdi32.dll stdcall';
function RemoveFontResourceEx(lpFileName: string;
  fl: DWORD; pdv: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'RemoveFontResourceEx{#AW}@gdi32.dll stdcall';

var
  FontFlags: DWORD;

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  FontName: string;
begin
  // extract the font file to the temporary folder
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MyFont.ttf');
  // this combination specifies the reservation of this font for use
  // in the setup process and that this font cannot be enumerated
  FontFlags := FR_PRIVATE or FR_NOT_ENUM;
  // add the font resource
  if AddFontResourceEx(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyFont.ttf'),
    FontFlags, 0) <> 0 then
  begin
    // note, that this is the name of the font, which doesn't have
    // to match to the font file name
    FontName := 'My Font Name';
    // the global setting of the WizardForm.Font property causes many
    // of its child controls to inherit this font; except those listed
    // below; their default font has changed and they lost the ability
    // to inherit the font from their parent so we must do it manually
    WizardForm.Font.Name := FontName;
    WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font.Name := FontName;
    WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Font.Name := FontName;
    WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Font.Name := FontName;
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  // remove the font resource
  RemoveFontResourceEx(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyFont.ttf'),
    FontFlags, 0);
end;
```

Comment: You're welcome! Soon or later you'll find that message dialogs do not use the font you've specified. They even cannot. It is by design and controlled by the operating system. Workaround would require some sort of global hook for `MessageBox` function calls, which is not a good way to stay friend with malware detection software.